# Set different icons for the same file extension in Windows

Tags: windows, format, icons, registry, shell-extensions

I wonder if there is a way to register different icons in Windows to the same file extension. Let me explain it better:

I have a program which does whatever to some multimedia files (.bmp, .jpg, .mp3, .avi, ...) and as a result it renames them appending a proper extension to differentiate them:

Before:

file1.jpg
file2.mp3
file3.zip

After:

file1.jpg.myext
file2.mp3.myext
file3.zip.myext

I'm able to register a file extension for the file types "myext" and asign them an icon, etc. But I wonder if there is a way for the resulting files to keep their icons based on the original extension, thus Windows will differentiate it somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wonder if you could register jpg.myext or mp3.myext?

Comment: Yes, but Windows only takes the last extension to paint the icon (in all tests I've carried out)

Comment: Just create a new icon handler: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx